# Markup getting erased in VS 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am using master pages, update panel, AJAX Tab container and also modalpopup extenders and other AJAX validation controls.  The line that is bold for Termination Reaon has a problem. I need to have `<asp:ListItem Text="Select Contract Termination Reason.." Value=""></asp:ListItem>` to control the error:

> 'ddlContractTerminationReason' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items"

It works but suddenly it started getting erased while trying to make some other changes to the application. If I try to type that again as soon as I click on Save, it gets erased and saves the file. My network administrator reinstalled everything for me assuming  that some virus problem but looks like something else is causing this. Any help on this greatly appreciated.

```
<tr> 
  <td> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlContractTerminationReason" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" CausesValidation="True" CssClass="dropdown extralong" DataSourceID="dsTerminationReason" DataTextField="ReasonDescription" DataValueField="TerminationReasonID">
      <asp:ListItem Text="Select Contract Termination Reason.."></asp:ListItem>            
    </asp:DropDownList> 
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cusValTerminationReason" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="RequireTerminationReason" ControlToValidate="ddlContractTerminationReason" ErrorMessage="Please enter Termination Reason OR Other Resson, if the Contractor is Terminated!" OnServerValidate="ServerValidateTerminationDate" SetFocusOnError="True" Text="*" ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="ContrMasterGroup"></asp:CustomValidator> 
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsTerminationReason" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Conn %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TerminationReasonID], [ReasonDescription] FROM [TerminationReasons] ORDER BY [ReasonDescription]"> </asp:SqlDataSource>
  </td>
  <td class="rightalign">
    <asp:Label ID="lblOtherContractTerminationReason" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="if Others, Explain:"></asp:Label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherContractTerminationReason" runat="server" CssClass="long" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox> 
  </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

After your DataBind execute this code

```
ddlContractTerminationReason.DataBind();
ddlContractTerminationReason.Items.Add("Select Contract Termination Reason..");
```